# Get count and one sample of has_many relationship with Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to append a sample product and products count for each category.

```
schema "category" do
  timestamps()
  field :title, :string
  has_many :products, Product
end
```

`result: %{title: “…”, sample_product: %Product{…}, products_count: xx}`

Is it possible with ecto and postgresql?

Comment: By _sample_ you mean the randomly selected from existing, a predefined one, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

For sample product, you should have another key (`sample_product_id`) in `categories` table and `belongs_to` field in `Category` schema.

There is no builtin solution for counter cache in Ecto, but it can be easily implemented with Postgres trigger and [read_after_writes option to a schema field](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3).

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the advice to introduce another cross-reference to `products` is awful. This will lead to hardly supported updates. If the product is to be predefined for each category, this is to be done as additional field in `products` table, `field :default_for_category, :boolean`.

Comment: Yes, probably. I've just said how to do what @mayTree wants: having sample_product field in the category. If you avoid to permanently delete your products (by using `deleted` flag for example), then you avoid such system to be a nightmare. I won't argue that it is good though. Better solution maybe is having sample_category_products table with category_id unique.

Answer (score 0):

I won't provide a ready to use answer, but maybe this will work as a nice starting point. I would start from building an SQL query that does it, cause once you see it's working, you can easily convert it into Ecto.

1. First part of the problem is to find a count of associated products. This can be done as follows:

   SELECT c.title, count(p.id) AS products_count FROM categories AS c JOIN products AS p ON p.category_id = c.id GROUP BY c.id;
2. Second part is to attach random product with each category. I don't know the way to do it in one query, you might have done it with nested SELECT, but performance would be very questionable, so I'd recommend to make another query, which would take category ids as parameter:

   SELECT DISTINCT(p.category_id) * FROM products AS p WHERE p.category_id IN (...) ORDER BY p.category_id, RANDOM();

Now you just need to rewrite it with Ecto. Let me know if you need help with that.